# Good implementations of MVC in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I've done some development in RoR and I'm now trying to make something in PHP.

I think the MVC architecture is an ideal frame for my current project (users, application data, purchases, etc.)

Is there implementation of MVC on the web that is recommended or does PHP just not work in the same way as Rails and every MVC in PHP must be hand made?

My google fu is weak and I couldn't really find anything conclusive.

Comment: Went with Codeigniter. Thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These four are MVC frameworks:

- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)

I prefer **CodeIgniter** and **Kohana**, because they're pretty focused and not bloated at all, and because they both, besides being MVC, are also big on the [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) principle, meaning you don't have to go around maintaining XML/YAML/etc config files of your classes, URL routes, etc.

In particular I like **Kohana** because it has this nifty file system-based configuration hierarchy (they call it "Cascading Filesystem") which basically means you have even less configuration nonsense to maintain, because based on *where* you put your app's files (classes, config files, etc), the framework will know which parts of the system will be overridden. So I'd recommend you give Kohana a test run. **Beware** though, it's relatively new and the documentation is kind of weak, so if your google fu is indeed weak as you say, then you might be better off going straight for CodeIgniter, which has been around for longer and thus has more docs. But I'd still keep an eye on the Kohana project.

**Symfony** is... too bloated for my taste (i.e. having to run scripts in order to "generate views" and whatnot), but I've seen some large successful projects running on it.

Comment: kohana is my most favourite. Worked with CodeIgniter/Kohana/CakePHP... Nothing is so simpler than Kohana

Answer (score 3):

Rails is an MVC framework, for PHP you could use [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) both of those use the MVC design pattern. CodeIgniter is the bomb.

Answer (score 3):

You can find more discussion about PHP frameworks here: http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-MVC-framework-for-PHP

I haven't looked into other frameworks, I have found Codeigniter to satisfy most of my requirements from an MVC framework.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, Theres Codeignitor and Frostbite Framework.. Both are good, and easy to find via google. Here is a whole list of php frameworks: http://matrix.include-once.org/framework/simple

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else pretty much nailed it. The only reason I'm adding on to this question is because you use Ruby on Rails, and as such, CakePHP is going to be the most similar framework for you.

I use CodeIgniter because it's very well-documented and lightweight (with very little magic), but that's just my personal preference. Cake will be most like what you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

I think laravel is best for you. Remember, frameworks are for SSBs Small scale businesses. For large scale businesses you write your own framework with all planning, execution phases etc.